# Is it possible to convert mts files to iso, burn them to a disk, and reverse the process later?

Tags: iso-image, dvd-burning

I have mts video files, is it possible, after having converted them to iso in order to burn them to blank dvds for storage, to then rip them from the same dvds and build them back into the original mts format?

Basically it is easiest to use them in their original format, and I want to back up the mts videos.

I have done a lot of searching which is why I came here, but it appears there is no free software that can reasonably put a .mts file onto a disc, or at least none that will not produce errors for me. Most often the program simply does not take mts as input in the first place.

I also am getting the impression that nobody writes software that will take a file in iso format and convert it into anything else, or there are very limited options in that department, certainly nothing that seems to do iso to mts.

I am simply going to find other space to put the mts data onto for the time being.

Comment: Why not simply burn them as files?

Comment: @kinokijuf When I try that I get I/O Error with imgburn, it says "SK Interpretation: Not Ready" and "ASC/ASCQ Interpretation: Cannot Write Medium - Incompatible Format" among other things. I probably just do not know how to do as you suggest, but that is basically why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you receive may be produced by the size of your mts files. The ISO DVD disc format allows file sizes up to 2 GB, other formats may allow bigger files.

For backup purposes you can split the original mts files into several smaller files. Common file compressing utilities like winzip or 7zip are capable of doing this. The smaller files can be burnt on DVD and can be recovered later on. After recovering the files from DVD the utility can reproduce the original mts file.

This even enables you to save video files that would not fit on one single DVD.

Comment: Actually that is probably why since the mts files are well over 2GB in size. And I did consider doing compression but I believe in order to retrieve the data I would need all of them in the same place to unzip them.

Comment: You can put the partial zip files on as many DVDs as you need. Just copy them all into one folder on your hard drive before unzipping them.

Answer (score 0):

If:

- all of the MTS files fit onto a single- or dual-layer DVD (4.7 or 8.5GB respectively), and
- you've saved the entire BDMV folder from the video camera

With some simple file renames and moves, you can arrange those files into a directory structure that when burned to a DVD is Blu-ray playable  (as long as the Blu-ray player can play AVCHD files).  Here's instructions I found on the web: http://www.avchduser.com/articles/avchd_to_bluray.jsp